# Speech Recognition to Play Audio

Tags: programming-languages, speech-recognition

I'm sorry if this has been covered, but I don't best know how to find what I'm looking for. I am looking to build a "training program" where new employees can ask a client a question, and the client responds based on the question. For example, if the employee asks for the client's name, they will respond with the name. If they ask for an address, etc. I would like the audio to be already recorded and saved somewhere, ready to be played when "activated" if you will by the employees words.

1. What keywords should I use to find help/documentation on the internet, or in books for this type of process besides just "speech recognition" and also:
2. What programming language(s) should I look to program this in?

Thanks for any help, I'm prepared to start from square 1 and go from there.

Comment: I understand that it may be necessary to buy/use software for the speech part, and then somehow integrate that with a programming language. I am not looking to develop my own speech library or program, but some tweaking to an existing library on software would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try [cmusphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/), [read their wiki](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/) and i recommend you start from the top by reading their excellent guide to basics about [speech recognition concepts](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialconcepts).

This is only the toolkit, it doesn't give you a wide catalog of reference sounds or models, which means that you will reasonably only be able to implement simple commands and it will be a lot of work.

See their FAQ specifically about [accuracy problems](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor).

**Keywords**

There's nothing wrong with "Speech Recognition", if you want aliases, pick one of the following from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition).

> In computer science, speech recognition (SR) is the translation of
>   spoken words into text. It is also known as "automatic speech
>   recognition", "ASR", "computer speech recognition", "speech to text",
>   or just "STT"